# Extract a decimal from a vector in maple

Tags: math-software, maple

Not sure if this question belongs in this form but I don't know where else to go.  I'm trying to index a matrix and do a < comparison on it.  Every time I try something like  A[1] it says:

Error, a Vector is not valid lhs to < or <=.

Can anyone help?

EXAMPLE:

A:=<1,2,3>:

b:=A[2]:

if b < 2 then .....

Comment: A matrix is a two-dimensional array of numbers. Why are you providing only one index?

Comment: sorry.  I reduce it down to a 1 dimensional 1x4 matrix (vector).

Comment: And what do you expect `<` to do on a vector? That's not usually defined.

Comment: What exactly did you feed Maple? If you don't show your exact input, none of us could be more helpful...

Comment: Adding to Henning's comment, you need to properly define < on vectors. For example, you can compare the n^th norms of vectors by _norm(A, n)_. Or you could compare the two vectors component-wise as follow. _C := zip((x,y) -> evalb(x < y), A, B);_ and then _andmap(\`=\`, C, true);_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Maple are you using?  For me, using Maple 12, the following works just fine:

```
A := <1,2,3>;
```

$$A := \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$

```
b := A[2];
```

$$b := 2$$

```
is(b < 2);
```

$$false$$

```
is(b <= 2);
```

$$true$$

Comment: yea well thats  what i was trying to do but for for some reason my if statement wouldn't work.  give you credit anyways